# Cordova app launcher plugin doesn't work for iOS to launch iOS app with uri

Tags: ios, cordova, launch

I need a help where I can launch the iOS app if is is installed on iPhone.

Plugin used for this is *cordova-plugin-app-launcher*, It is working fine in android, but in iOS it is not launching the app. I am using the below code, any help will be appreciated.

```
window.plugins.launcher.launch({
                uri: "fb://",
            }, () => {
                console.log('Success')
            }, () => {
                console.log('Error')
            });
```

Comment: Hi Priya and welcome to SO. In order to get better answers I would suggest that you include any error message to guide possible contributors in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Can you check "canLaunch" method and check if any error is returned?

Comment: Hei , I tried with the canLaunch method for iOS but it is not going inside the method. It is not doing anything..no error no success. I am not getting any error in both the cases but it doesnt launch the app.

Comment: Can you check whether the .h and .m files are in src folde and also "cordova-plugin-queries-schemes" plugin is added as mentioned in their installation guide?

Comment: I added this plugin cordova-plugin-queries-schemes suggested by you. but still it is not launching the app. Am I missing anything?

Comment: if (device.platform === "iOS") {
                window.plugins.launcher.launch({
            uri: "gatgo:",
            successCallback_ios,
            errorCallback_ios
        }),
        function successCallback_ios() {
            window.plugins.launcher.launch({
                uri: "gatgo://",
            }, () => {
                console.log('Success')
            }, () => {
                console.log('Error')
            });

        }

Comment: Here, you are calling launch for two times.. Instead can you make the first one as canLauch like below, just to see if any errors are getting printed and also write the errorCallback_ios function as well.. Here errorCallback_ios is not defined..

Comment: if (device.platform === "iOS") { window.plugins.launcher.canLaunch({uri: "gatgo:", successCallback_ios, errorCallback_ios});
function successCallback_ios() { window.plugins.launcher.launch({ uri: "gatgo://",}, () => { console.log('Success')}, () => {console.log('Error')});}
function errorCallback_ios() {  window.plugins.launcher.launch({ uri: 'https://apps.apple.com/no/app/visma-gatgo/id1303560961'}, () => {console.log('Success') }, () => { console.log('Error')  }); }

Comment: I tried this ,it is not going inside canLaunch method ..it is coming out of that method and no launch of the app. It is only issue with iOS. Android I am able to launch the app.

Comment: No error, I tried using app-availability plugin to check the app is available or not and then window.open() to launch the app. It is working fine now. But could't get through the app launcher plugin for iOS.

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this? I'm currently facing the same issue. Can launch external app on Android using "farmcam2" but not able to launch it on iOS. The URL Scheme is correct.